# How to Convert InstallSchema.php to Db_Schema.xml in Magento 2 ? is Possible Or Not

Tags: magento2.4.4

InstallSchema file ko Dbschema file me kaise convert kare.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try this https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/migration-scripts/

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the following steps to successfully Migrate your install/upgrade scripts to declarative schema

- Go to your database search for setup_module table and delete all the
  modules for which you want to have db_schema.xml
- Now Paste your module/s in the Vendor directory
  app\code\vendor\module
- Then Give Permissions - `sudo chmod -R 777`
- Convert your schema by pasting the following command.

`bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1`

`bin/magento setup:upgrade --convert-old-scripts=1`

Answer (score -1):

bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-patch [options] module-name patch-name